# arduino esp8266webserver error in returning json

Tags: jquery, json, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

In my arduino sketch I have this code:

```
void handleRoot() {
  server.send ( 200, "application/json", "{success:true,deviceID:'bla'}" );
}
```

so my arduino gets ip from my wifi AP(192.168.0.100) and in my js code of the client I have this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://192.168.0.100/",
  success: function(responseData) {
        alert(responseData);
},
});
```

but alert(responseData) don't even fire up...
I check in the browser console and I see that I getting this:

response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 29
Connection: close
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

and in the response content I have this:

```
{success:true,deviceID:'bla'}
```

why isn't this content not appear in the alert?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below samples :

```
server.send(200, "text/plain", "{\"success\":1,\"deviceID\":\"bla\"}");
```

and parse at the Ajax side :

```
JSON.parse(responseData);
```